# Analytics + Facebook tracking Javascript issue with document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]

Tags: javascript, facebook, e-commerce, analytics

I'm trying to understand if there is a conflict in the code by putting Facebook's tracking code on the same page as Analytics, because this line appears in both scripts:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
```

Here is the relevant code below:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

  <!---- START OF FACEBOOK TRACKING SCRIPT  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var fb_param = {};
    fb_param.pixel_id = '6008770441xxx';
    fb_param.value = '123.00';
    (function(){
      var fpw = document.createElement('script');
      fpw.async = true;
      fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
```

THIS LINE HERE:

```
      var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
    })();
   </script>
   <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=600877044xxx&amp;value=0" /></noscript>

  <!---- START OF ANALYTICS TRACKING SCRIPT  -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
     _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2725xxx-3']);
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
     _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
       '456',       // order ID - required
       'xxx', // affiliation or store name
       '123', // total - required
       '',    // tax
       '10',  // shipping
       ',     // city
       '',    // state or province
       'Australia' // country
     ]);      
  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

THIS LINE AGAIN:

```
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer next line after that line,

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

Now, this will insert the element in the First CHild Place, and who ever is first will become second,

so this is just to insert the script on run time, will NOT CONFLICT at all

:)

Comment: Thanks. So you're sure it won't insert into the Facebook 'script' twice?

Comment: What ever it will insert, it will not be conflicting, the script is inserted at the same place(first child), so the other will become second child, the the script is in different script tag. You need not worry, if it inserted twice, it had smart codes within the scripts, they will check it :)